# Spam link sets cookie(s) then redirects to google.com - what would be the point of this? Should I be concerned?

Tags: attacks, cookies, chrome, spam

Received a spam link about "a package soon to be delivered" via an SMS message. Didn't click it in my phone, but couldn't help myself but to go to the URL in a browser on my laptop :grimace: (not great, I realize, spare me the lectures).

There were no response bodies - seems the only thing it did was set headers and of course possibly log any information it could get about me from the initial request.

Wondering if anyone can speculate intelligently about the possible purpose of this and if I appear at a high risk of having been compromised in any way? I have cleared the cookies and other browser data and restarted the browser.

Here's the gist of it:

[image: initial request]
[image: redirect]
[image: ultimately at google]

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to defeat mail security filters that check links contained in mails whether they lead to a malicious site.
The link in the mail goes to a redirection under the control of the attacker.
When the mail is delivered the redirection goes to a harmless site so the filter lets it pass.
Later when the mail has been delivered but not yet read, they arm it by switching the redirection to a malicious site.

Comment: It could also be deciding whether to deliver a payload or redirect based on the request headers. A desktop browser has a different user agent to a mobile (where an SMS would typically be received).